# How to dynamically increase the page Header height in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to increase the height of the page header dynamically. There is a parameter to increase or decrease the size of the page header. ie, By default or If Parameter value is "Yes" then increase the size of the header to 1.5 inch. If param value is "No" then decrease height to 0.5 inches.

I tried many approaches like, Inserting textbox into page header and through line break increasing and decreasing the height. But, when exported to pdf, the changes in height is not showing correctly.

Any help to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to dynamically change the height of the page header in an SSRS report, since the page header height does not allow expressions. Why do you need to adjust the page header from a parameter value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to provide extra space in header if user willing to go for it. Because user's printing page may have letter head in their printing sheets or may not. So, by providing option to extra space, the user can make use of it. Otherwise, the printing sheets letter head may overlap our report content.

Comment: While still not a dynamic solution, consider using the Report Margins for this instead of the Page Header. The most "dynamic" solution I can come up with, is to create a copy of the report with wider margins, for when printing.

Comment: I am not able to get your solution

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. One need only be a little creative :)

- Create a Textbox in your Report Header and put it out of the way to one side, all the way to the top of the Header.
- Set the size of the Textbox to .01in x .5in.
- Set all the Padding of the Textbox to 0in except for the Top.
- Set the Top Padding: `=iif(Parameters!YourParameterName.Value = "Yes","0.5in","1.5in")`

Here are some pics of a test I did.
[image: Increase Header Height = False]

[image: Increase Header Height = True]

Instead of a "Yes/No" Parameter, you could even have a Float Parameter and have the user enter in the Header Height in inches. To do this, do the same as above only set the Top Textbox Padding to: `=Parameters.YourHeaderHeightParameter.Value & "in"`.

Comment: I have tried your way of setting report header height. But, Still it does not effect when exported to pdf format. Is that PDF wont support this kind of formatting ??

Comment: That might be it. Another thing you could try is moving the page header to multiple group headers of various heights and dynamically hide them based on your parameter. You can set them to repeat at the top of each page just like a page header.