# SSRS - Dynamically shrink header

Tags: reporting-services

I need to shrink dynamically height of header on ssrs

I have found answer on: [How to dynamically increase the page Header height in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855384/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-page-header-height-in-ssrs-2008) , but still I have problems as follows.

I have SSRS with several text boxes, (10 lines), and I want to show only one line for page 2 and after, and for page 1 - all of the lines.

I cannot shrink the size, because minimum size of header by default is the maximum element bottom position.

Can I control the size of height of the header dynamically?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page header and footers can not be dynamically sized. This allows support for more output devices but limits its use for many situations. A common work around is to use a Parent group above all others in your dataset that has a sql command that returns 1 row such as `SELECT OneRow=1`. You could place your header logic in this print once groups header and optionally show or hide the header based on first page last page etc.

Comment: How can I add business logic for the header? I need to show fields on the header on first page, and on second page - not showing them (but always show the body section).